# Regular Expressions on variable in Perl

Tags: perl, perlscript

I have value `E.1.1.1` in a variable, I want `E111` stored in different variable.

```
$var1 = "E.1.1.1";
$var1 =~ s/\.//g;
```

The above code changes the value in `$var1` variable. I want to try as below.

```
$var2 = s/\.//g $var1;
```

Suggest how to do. I am new to Perl.

Comment: Try: `(my $var2 = $var1) =~ s/\.//g` or use the `r` modifier

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
(my $var2 = $var1) =~ s/\.//g;
```

Comment: On newish perls: `my $var2 = $var1 =~ s/\.//gr;`

Answer (score 2):

```
my $var2 = $var1;
$var2 =~ s/\.//g;
```

or

```
( my $var2 = $var1 ) =~ s/\.//g;
```

or

```
my $var2 = $var1 =~ s/\.//gr;    # 5.14+
```

Answer (score 0):

You already got universal answers using `s///`.

For this specific task, *removing `.` from a string* , you can also use the `y` (alias `tr`).

```
( my $var2 = $var1 ) =~ y/.//d;
```

or

```
my $var2 = $var1 =~ y/.//dr; #the /r needs 5.14+
```

More info: [perlop - Quote-Like Operators](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)